# How to store server side data to client side variable in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My server side function retrieves some spreadsheet data. I want to store that data in a client side variable, inside a script tag:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var data = new Array();
    data =google.script.run.getData(); // getData() is server side function.
}
```

When I use console.log for `data`, it is not showing anything.
Have I called `google.script.run` in the correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added javascript tag. Improved grammer/spelling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a callback function to retrieve the data when your server side function runs successfully.

```
function myFunction() { 
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();
}

function onSuccess(data) {
    //the argument data contains the array
}
```

See this document for more information and examples.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run